# 1 big merge publication or N small ones?

Tags: sql-server, performance, windows

### **Scenario**

We have two servers, each one with its own *Microsoft SQL Server*

1. Serv_Home
2. Serv_Web

In both servers, a local program works with its own local database and inserts/updates the tables. The data is shared between the 2 servers, and for this purpose we have several replicas. *Serv_Home* is the *master* server (the distributor of the publications).

A specific table must be copied from *Serv_Home* to *Serv_Web* (not viceversa), so the publication is a *Snapshot*.

For all the rest, a *Merge publication* is used. We decided to create 5 Merge publications, one for each group of tables which are more or less related. The reason why we have 5 instead of a big single one is simply convenience. Everything works fine.

Lately though, we are experiencing a *high CPU usage in Serv_Home* (like 50% sometimes) due to the *sqlservr.exe* process.

---

### Question

*Is it better to have a big single Merge publication instead of N small ones? Could this be a performance bottleneck?*

I know that the best way is to try it myself, but we are in a production environment and it would be messy to redo it all. Some documentation or good reasoning would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been looking for an answer to no avail.

However, I've found a [place](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/169349/Multiple-publications-or-just-one) where some advantages are mentioned:

1. Easier to maintain.
2. Multiple data streams going to the subscription database at once (hopefully).
3. If the merge fails for a publication, only this publication has to be fixed and reinitialized.

So I think there would be no performance improvement having just 1 big one publication. On the contrary, if the data streams are parallel, we can even get a better performance when splitting the merge in N small publications.